# Use methods from class one in a method in class two

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got an assignment (written in java) that is very specific in terms of interfaces and how and where to implement all sorts of stuff. And I know that alot of similiar questions have been asked but I can't seem to connect them with my problem.

The class i have to implement is

```
 public class Algorithm<G extends Game<M>, M extends Move>
implements AIp<M>
```

I am not allowed to change that name. The method in this class has to implement a few methods from the class `G`.

The interface `Game` which is implemented in `G` contains a few methods like `makeMove()` or `evaluateSituation()` (We are playing Connect four here).

I've implemented all the methods from both Interfaces in seperate classes so far and I also created a playing `Board` (class). In `G` I created a board object on which the game is played.

So my questions is: how do I use the methods from the class `G` and the class `Board` in my method (in `Algorithm`) without creating a new object of `Board` (cause I already have that) and/or `G`.

Edit:

```
public class Algorithm<G extends Game<M>, M extends Move> implements AIp<M> {

    G g;

    public Algorithm(G g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public someMethod() {
         g.getBoard().someMethodFromBoard();
         // The line above gives the following error:
         // The method getBoard() is undefined for the type G.
         // 1 quick fix available: Add cast to 'g'.
    }


}


        public class G {
             public Board getBoard() {
                 return somelist;
             }
}
```

someList isn't implemented in Game.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your concept I think you can simply declare getter method for `Board` object in `Game` class and implement it in `G`.

```
class G 
{
...
    public Board getBoard() 
    {
        return theBoardYouCreatedInG;
    }    
}
```

If you already have `G` object then just provide it in the constructor of `Algorithm`. Then you just use the `G` object and its getter method to get `Board` object

```
public class Algorithm<G extends Game<M>, M extends Move> implements AIp<M>
{

    G g;

    public Algorithm(G g) 
    {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public someMethod()
    {
         g.someMethodFromG();
         g.getBoard().someMethodFromBoard();
    }


}
```

EDIT:
If you want to use your code this way, you need getBoard() implemented in `Game`. If that's not possible then I guess you will have to provide `Board` object in the constructor (like you did with G object)

And G is not supposed to be a real class, it's a type parameter for some class that you will specify later (in this case, any class that implements `Game`), if you want to use methods of `G` they need to be declared in `Game`.

Comment: wait. I don't have a G object. I do have a Board object created in G. So using g.getBoard().someBoardMethod() isn't working. g.someMethodFromG() is however.

Comment: Adding a `G` object isn't an option because the algorithm has to be generic and not specific to `G` or the game connect four. E.g. you would have to be able to play tic tac toe with it.

Comment: `G` object here means any `Game` object. If you want to play tic tac toe then you should have `TicTacToe` class that inherits from `Game` right?

Comment: Ok but shouldn't the fourth line of your second code part initialize `Game g;` instead of `G g;` then?

Comment: In the first line you have `<G extends Game<M>` so G is a type parameter for any type that implements `G`

Comment: Well that makes sense to me. But I can only implement the methods from the Interface Game with g.someMethod(). However I did initialize the variable `G g;` and I don't understand why I can't use the methods from G.

If I place the someMethodFromBoard() in the interface `Game` I can reach the method with `g.getBoard().someMethodFromBoard();`. That seems wrong to me. And as I said before I am not allowed to change the interface